# jquery svg: get attributes of external loaded svg

Tags: jquery, svg

I load an external svg with the svg-plugin

```
<svg version="1.2" baseProfile="tiny" id="fig" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
x="0px" y="0px" width="200px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 200 100" overflow="inherit" xml:space="preserve">
<ellipse id="obj" cx="100" cy="50" rx="20" ry="40"/>
</svg>
```

When the svg is loaded, I can get the bbox or the boundingClientRect but not the width (200px)

```
var boxW = svg.getElementById('fig').getBBox().width;
var bcrW = svg.getElementById('fig').getBoundingClientRect().width;
```

How can I get the values of attribute of the svg (with the id='fig') ?

Thanks

the svg is loaded with the svg-plugin for jquery

```
myDiv.css( "width", "144px" );
myDiv.css( "height", "72px" );
myDiv.svg({loadURL: "test_01.svg", onLoad: svgLoaded});
```

and

```
function svgLoaded( svg ) {
var myWidth = svg.getElementById('fig').getAttributeNS(null, 'width');
```

myWidth is now 144, thus the width of the wrapper-div not the width defined inside the svg (200px)

Answer (score 0):

If you catch `#fig` with

```
svg.getElementById('fig');
```

then you only have to do:

```
svg.getElementById('fig').getAttributeNS(null, 'width');
```

EDIT: More complete example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<embed src="rect01.svg" type="image/svg+xml"/>

<script>
    var emb, svg, w;

    emb = document.querySelector('embed');

    emb.addEventListener('load', function () {
      svg = emb.getSVGDocument().querySelector('#fig'); // also works with .documentElement
      w   = svg.getAttributeNS(null, 'width');
      console.log(w);
    });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This gets the width and the height of the wrapper div not the values of the original attributes

Comment: Is the svg script on another domain?

Comment: I updated with a more complete example, is this not what you want?

Comment: Thank you bennedich, your solution works. I load the svg with the svg-plugin for query as shown in my expanded question. Then I get the width of the div not the attribute inside the svg